# Finding largest sublist in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

How do I find the largest sublist in this context?

Given a set of data of n pixels RGB values

e.g. n = 3

pixel[1]: 255, 255, 255 pixel[2]: 0, 20, 0 pixel[3]: 5, 13, 63

Find the largest sublist(number of pixels) that satisfy this condition: A × (R - rmin) + B × (G - gmin) + C × (B - bmin) ≤ D, where A, B, C and D are constants taken from user input. rmin, gmin, bmin are the miminimu RGB values of the pixels in the sublist respectively.

e.g. Using the example data set above, a sublist size = 2, containing pixel[2] & pixel[3], rmin = 0, gmin = 13, bmin = 0

What I did was setup an array for taking in the pixel data and put it in a doubly nested for-loop, the 1st one to count the different possible starting pixels and the second one to add an extra pixel and see if that extra pixel satisfy the condition. If it does not satisfy, loop will end and the number of pixels will be stored in an array corresponding to the starting pixel.

However, it is obviously wrong as the algorithm does not consider all the different combinations. The method assumes that the pixels increase in a numerical order which in this case cannot be sorted in numerical order as each pixels have 3 corresponding values. I am also unable to sort them A × (R - rmin) + B × (G - gmin) + C × (B - bmin), as the minimum values varies with each subset.

Thanks For The Help :)

Comment: "In this exercise" - another school homework?

Comment: Nope, but I'm taking practice questions from schools.

Comment: I see. Learnt something new today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather loop through a string via a pointer and if a pointer starts some word (try `strncmp` and `strlen`), I'd shift the whole string to the left, like "ALPHA BETA" -> "ABETA" using `memmove`.

Also note that in case if you call `return` statement, the function returns **immediately**. If you want to stop the loop, use `break` statement. If you want to skip a single iteration, use `continue` statement.